# How to do string suffix replace with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a file that has configuration values as below

```
name=value
path=/root/home/
F_path=~/root
ip=12.23.523
```

I want to replace the value with given keys.

Example

```
st.replace('^F_path', 'xxx');
```

output should be

```
name=value
path=/root/home/
F_path=xxx
ip=12.23.523
```

I can match prefix and replace that string but I can't fix suffix match with regex and replace suffix string.

Comment: See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA8qE5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a regex with a multiline flag to force `^` match the beginning of a line:

```
/^F_path=.+/m
```

Here is a snippet with a `replace` example:

```js
var str = 'name=value\npath=/root/home/\nF_path=~/root\nip=12.23.523';
var res = str.replace(/^F_path=.+/m, 'F_path=xxx');
alert(res);
```

Note we do not need any capturing groups since we are not interested in that text.